# Emacs text gets stuck in minibuffer

Tags: emacs, minibuffer

I am using GNU Emacs 24.4.1 (edit: also seen with 24.5.1).  Some old output from vc-mode (I think) is appearing in the minibuffer:

```
Auto-merging foo/bar
```

I am not doing any version control operations at the moment, but this text is stuck in the minibuffer.  Pressing C-g replaces it briefly with Quit, but it comes back with the next keystroke.

What it isn't: it's not a recursive edit.  C-] or `abort-recursive-edit` gives the error `No recursive edit is in progress` and the awkward text in the minibuffer is still there.

It's not text selected with the mouse since I am running in a text console (GNU screen session over ssh) with no mouse support.

I have tried the `switch-to-minibuffer` command from http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/MiniBuffer but that gives the error `Minibuffer is not active`.  Yet still this awkward text keeps appearing.

It is not a screen size problem (with stale text because Emacs is not aware of the correct size of the terminal window) because I can resize the terminal window and Emacs resizes with it correctly... with the text still displayed in the minibuffer.

Sometimes I have seen this effect with two or more lines of text in the minibuffer.  In fact, my current Emacs session has that in one client session (`emacsclient -nw`) in one screen, with the main session showing only one line.  The client session shows several lines of version control gunk in the minibuffer:

```
Auto-merging foo/bar
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in foo/bar
```

How can I make it go away?

Comment: Assumption: it sounds like the text remains even after you move the cursor, type text, etc.  
Does the text show up in the `*Messages*` buffer?  Have you tried `M-: (message nil)`? To see if that can clear it up?

Comment: Thanks - next time this occurs I will try what you suggest.  Oddly it hasn't happened since upgrading to emacs 24.5.1...

Comment: No, the text does not show in `*Messages*`.  It is a fragment of `*Shell Command Output*` which has got stuck in the minibuffer.  Doing `M-: (message nil)` prints `nil` in the minibuffer, but it then goes back to showing the fragment of shell output.

Comment: The way I have found to clear it is `M-! echo`.

Comment: Thanks! Your comment worked. This has driven me crazy in the past.

Comment: Actually my *Shell Command Output* window got stuck after doing this.  This post has a complete solution that worked for me: http://emacs.1067599.n8.nabble.com/bug-25209-25-1-can-t-delete-Shell-Command-Output-tp415873p416155.html

Answer (score 3):

This could happen if you hit `C-g` to terminate a running shell command.  This would leave the minibuffer window pointing to the `*Shell Command Output*` buffer.

As described in [bug #25209](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=25209), you could check whether that has happened by calling `(minibuffer-window)` in the scratch buffer:

```
(minibuffer-window)
#<window 2 on *Shell Command Output*>
```

and fix it with:

```
(set-window-buffer (minibuffer-window) (get-buffer " *Minibuf-0*"))
```

This has been fixed in [this commit](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/commit/?id=85aebc12de28667cdccde5b080972453544d015e), and the fix was released as part of Emacs 26.1.

Comment: Thanks, that's likely to have been it (or a closely related bug).  As you say, it appears fixed in recent Emacs versions.

Comment: I'm getting this in Emacs 28.1. Your solution fixes the issue, indeed.