# How to clear Emacs echo area in my program?

Tags: emacs, echo, minibuffer

I have this code:

```
(defun do-repeated-work (args)
"some work that need executed repeatedly"
(message nil) 
(message "doing some repeated work, arg = %s, current time = %s" args (format-time-string "%H:%M:%S")))

(setq timer (run-with-idle-timer 3 t 'do-repeated-work (list "arg1" "arg2" "arg3")))
```

The purpose of the code above is: print a line of message in minibuffer repeatedly every three seconds. But I found that, when the function `do-repeated-work` works again, the old message in emacs minibuffer cannot be cleared, so the new message cannot be displayed. I have already tried the way mentioned in this question: [how to empty or clear the emacs minibuffer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28830990/how-to-empty-or-clear-the-emacs-minibuffer), but it doesn't work.

My Emacs version is 25.3

How to cope with this problem?

Comment: `(message nil)` works for me, Emacs 25.3.50.1 on MacOS High Sierra. Demo: `(progn (message "Hello ...") (sit-for 1) (message nil) (sit-for 1) (message "Hello ... done."))`

Comment: And as noted in the other question, that's the "echo area", not properly the "minibuffer".

Comment: `(message nil)` works well in your case, it's actually a good solution in those cases like that. But in my case, the root cause is I wrongly use the `idle` function. Anyhow, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've made an incorrect assumption, and consequently your problem isn't what you think it is.

> The purpose of the code above is: print a line of message in minibuffer repeatedly every three seconds.

That's not what it does.

You've used `run-with-idle-timer` which will run *one time* once Emacs has been idle for 3 (in this case) seconds, and will not repeat *until* some non-idle activity has taken place -- after which it will again run once Emacs has become idle for 3 seconds.

See <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>f</kbd> `run-with-idle-timer`

If you want something which repeats at a consistent interval, use `run-with-timer`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer:) My understanding for the usage of `run-with-idle-timer` is wrong. `run-with-timer`  solve my problem, great!